# Why do all states have equal representation in the U.S. Senate, regardless of population?

Tags: united-states, senate, population

For example, while California (population: 39,144,818) has two senators to represent them, Wyoming (population: 586,107) also has two senators to represent them. The population of California is more than 66 times the population of Wyoming, but California and Wyoming still have equal representation in the Senate.

The Senate has a great amount of power when it comes to passing legislation and approving Supreme Court nominees. Though, a Wyomingite's vote counts significantly more than a Californian's vote.

Comment: It's not a defect, it's a feature.

Comment: @user1530 Asking why something is does not imply that one thinks it's a defect.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Because it was a compromise struck at the [Constitutional Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutional_Convention_(United_States)) between the large colonies like Virginia and New York, and the smaller colonies like Connecticut and Rhode Island that all states would get an equal say in the Senate to prevent the large states from forcing their policies on the Smaller states.

It was known as the [Connecticut Compromise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutional_Convention_(United_States)#Connecticut_Compromise). This was done because the states have rights too, and each state will have an equal say in matters before the senate.

The other side of the compromise was that the House of Representatives *does* have proportional representation. Roughly speaking, the idea was for the House to represent the people and the Senate to represent the states.

Comment: +1 Note that the other side of the compromise was proportional representation in the House. Roughly speaking, the idea was for the House to represent the people and the Senate to represent the states.

Comment: This question should be expanded to include the role of federalism and states right's generally as beneficial to liberty, self-governance and limited government that put important checks on potentially despotic and far away central governments.

Comment: @KDog - While I tend to agree that these principles when applied as intended do, they can also be used to oppress as was done throughout the US south in the 50's and 60s.

Comment: It could be worth noting that under the Articles of Confederation, each state had equal representation also. So it was something of the norm at the time.

Comment: @indigochild - Actually the US was literally groundbreaking in its form of government and democracy.  It was definately not the norm.  The AoC were not meeting the needs of the new nation which is why they agreed to  reform the government in the first place.  I would say that it is true that the smaller states did not want to give up all of their power that they had in the AoC but they also realized it was not going to last and that the larger states would be likely to break away unless the compromise was  struck.  Which would have left the smaller states vulnerable.

Comment: @DeplorableNumber9035768 - The Constitution was groundbreaking. Confederations were already well known in the 18th century; you can pick up histories like Thucydides' and find confederations of city-states easily.

Comment: @indigochild - You should create your own answer then.

Comment: It should also be noted that the members of the senate used to be picked by the state legislators and not the people in the state.

Comment: @JoeW indeed, it was more than just an "idea" that one house represented the states and the other the people.